# Python Selenium WebDriver. How to get the href link?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the `href` link using Python and Selenium WebDriver but the statement is returning an empty list.

HTML

`<a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX?ref=br_rs"><span>Ma....</span></a>`

Python code

`urls = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('._32mo [href]')`

Thank you

Comment: can you include the url?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[el.get_attribute("href") for el in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("._32mo")]
```

[ref](https://chercher.tech/python/webelement-commands)